# How to wait for socket communication in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```
@tree.command(name = "test" , description = 'socket')
async def bot_command(interaction, var : str):
    msg = {"platform":"discord"}
    msg['command'] = "test"
    msg['var'] =var
    await interaction.response.send_message(sendsocket(msg)[0:2000])
```

Usually the above code works fine. But when anything more than 3 seconds is done on the server, discord.py throws an error. It looks like a timeout error. Any way to make discord.py wait for socket?

There is a 'wait_for' part in the API, but it is difficult to solve because there are examples only for message responses.

Comment: What does your `sendsocket` function do and why are you doing it?

Comment: Sending a message from discord.py sends a socket to the server. In a way, it is a simple task to work on the server and send the socket to discord.py again, but it does not work if there is a delay. If I do the same thing in html, it works fine. I kept searching, but it seems that I need to use create_thread.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at using [`defer`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.defer) - I'm assuming the error you're getting is that the interaction no longer exists and you're getting a "Interaction failed" message in Discord UI.

```py
@tree.command(name = "test" , description = 'socket')
async def bot_command(interaction, var : str):
    # tells discord we need a few seconds to process
    await interaction.response.defer()
    msg = {"platform":"discord"}
    msg['command'] = "test"
    msg['var'] = var
    thing_to_send = sendsocket(msg)[0:2000]
    # use followup rather than response as we have already "responded" with the defer
    await interaction.followup.send(thing_to_send)
```

We do have to use [`followup.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Webhook) rather than `response.send_message` after using `defer` though.

If your `sendsocket` function is taking that long to respond - it might be worth looking at doing that asynchronously as well. You would still have to `defer` and `followup` here but it would free up resoureces whilst waiting for the function to return.

### Why multiple commands will still fail

If you try and run multiple commands simultaneously, you'll still get an error message on one of the command invocations complaining about the unknown interaction. I'm pretty sure this is because `sendsocket` is blocking and not using coroutines and that's causing issues. I tested this:

(I'm using `pycord` so forgive some of the differing syntax for defined commands - the important bits are the same though)

```py
# my mock "sendsocket" func
def sendsocket():
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    return "done"

@client.command()
async def test(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    await ctx.defer()
    msg = sendsocket()
    await ctx.followup.send(content=msg)
```

Running this and trying to invoke as many application commands as I could - at least one would always fail with `Unknown Interaction`. This was actually on the `defer()` call. Because `sendsocket` is blocking and waiting for the whatever to happen, not all the `/test` commands are being executed instantly and are waiting for others ahead to get processed. When they try to `defer()`, the interaction has already exceeded the 3 seconds and the command will fail.

To fix this, we need to make our code asynchronous using coroutines. In my example:

```py
async def sendsocket():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return "done"

@client.command()
async def test(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    await ctx.defer()
    msg = await sendsocket()
    await ctx.followup.send(content=msg)
```

This completely resolved the issue and I wasn't able to reproduce.

In short, you need to make whatever `sendsocket` is doing asynchronous with coroutines so that the entire bot isn't waiting for the server/socket to return the data you want to send in a message. If you make asynchronous, then your bot can process other commands/things whilst it's waiting for the response. I'm not entirely sure what you're doing in `sendsocket` but I'd start by looking at the `asyncio` library as there's methods in there for dealing with sockets and streams asynchronously. Or look at something like `aiohttp` for web requests,etc.

Comment: It works amazingly. Fantastic. I was implementing it using 'client.loop.create_task' to solve it by myself. But using your answer, it works really neatly. thank you

Comment: Glad it helped! If you could, please mark the answer as the solution/answer to denote it's been answered.

Comment: If you run it once while the task is running, 'discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction' error seems to occur. Do you know a solution to prevent this?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's because `sendsocket` is blocking so the interaction is timing out before your other invoked commands can use `defer()`. I'd wager that's where the error traceback is saying what failed. You will need to make `sendsocket()` asynchronous so that it becomes non-blocking and other commands can process and use `defer()` before they time out. I've edited my answer with a test I ran and a longer explanation.